# horizontal align table head text and icon

Tags: html, css

I have an table but the icon is not algining horizontally with the text. When the table header text is to long the icon shows up under the text like this: 
[image]

Here is the html of the table header:

```
<thead class="thead-default">
        <tr><th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>id
              <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=id"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
            <th>benaderd
              <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=approached"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
            <th>naam
               <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=name"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
            <th>skills
              <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=skills"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
            <th>email
              <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=email"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
            <th>telefoon
              <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=mobile"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
            <th>stad
              <a href="/web/app_dev.php/candidates?sort=desc&amp;cat=city"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```

Here is the scss code:

```
.table {
    .thead-default {
        th {
            //&:nth-of-type(3){
            //    display: inline-flex;
            //}
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #4a4a4a;
            text-transform: uppercase;

            @include media-breakpoint-up(md){
                //&:nth-of-type(2) {
                //    width: 80px;
                //}
                //
                //&:last-of-type {
                //    width: 95px;
                //}
            }
        }
    }

    td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .profile-pic {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 100%;

        .initial {
            height: 100%;
            color: #fff;
        }
    }

    a {
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .more_horiz {
            line-height: 36px;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I align the icon with the table header text? As you see I first tried to set the width of the table header.

Comment: can you please provide the entire code of the navbar? with the css, please...

Comment: it seems your th has fixed max-width which causes icons on some places to go on second line

Comment: Please provide your css code for th tag

Comment: add the complete code of the table

Comment: _If_ this is the full scss, then you have to define your imported mixin `media-breakpoint-up`, which you can verify if you paste the code into [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/).  Otherwise, you will need to post the full CSS after it is compiled.

Comment: De mixin is working but it is about the table header where the text has to align with the icon